# jpackage FileSystemException

Tags: java, macos, jpackage

I have a Java project (on Mac OSX and in Eclipse) where jpackage produces an error I don't understand

The jpackage command is as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.5.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

jpackage \
    --type app-image \
    -i ../Released \
    -d ../Released \
    -n "Boekhouding" \
    --app-version "1.3.7" \
    --icon ../../Images/euro.icns \
    --main-jar run.jar \
    --verbose
```

This jpackage version and command works with another project but not with this project. The error is as follows:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/cor/SoftwareProjects/Boekhouding/Desktop/Build/../Released/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents/app/Boekhouding.app/Contents: File name too long
```

This project was succesfully packaged with jpackage of jdk 11.0.3.

Does anyone have a clue what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

You have used same input and output dir parameters `-i` and `-d`, so you are seeing a recursive copy of one to the other - probably getting deeper levels each time you run the command. Use separate folders for each parameter.

The `--dest` / `-d` value is more suitable to be set as a temporary build location so it can be cleared by a "clean" operation of whatever build system you use and regenerated cleanly by next run.